# EditorFor is not naming the created fields correctly when I cast the model field

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

I have a viewmodel that contains a Transaction which has a field called PaymentMethod. PaymentMethod points to an abstract class PaymentMethodInfo that will be one of two types, CheckPaymentMethodInfo or MoneyOrderPaymentMethodInfo. When I create the form I check which type it is and render the correct fields. The code looks like this:

```
@if (Model.Transaction.PaymentMethod.FundingMethod == FundingMethod.MoneyOrder) {
                <div id="money_order_payment">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => ((MoneyOrderPaymentMethodInfo) model.Transaction.PaymentMethod).Originator,
                            new {@class = "control-label col-md-2"})
                        <div class="col-md-10">
                            @Html.EditorFor(model => ((MoneyOrderPaymentMethodInfo) model.Transaction.PaymentMethod).Originator,
                                new {htmlAttributes = new {@class = "form-control"}})
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => ((MoneyOrderPaymentMethodInfo) model.Transaction.PaymentMethod).Originator, "",
                                new {@class = "text-danger"})
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => ((MoneyOrderPaymentMethodInfo) model.Transaction.PaymentMethod).SerialNumber,
                            new {@class = "control-label col-md-2"})
                        <div class="col-md-10">
                            @Html.EditorFor(model => ((MoneyOrderPaymentMethodInfo) model.Transaction.PaymentMethod).SerialNumber,
                                new {htmlAttributes = new {@class = "form-control"}})
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => ((MoneyOrderPaymentMethodInfo) model.Transaction.PaymentMethod).SerialNumber, "",
                                new {@class = "text-danger"})
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            } else {
                <div id="check_payment">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => ((CheckPaymentMethodInfo) model.Transaction.PaymentMethod).BankName,
                            new {@class = "control-label col-md-2"})
                        <div class="col-md-10">
                            @Html.EditorFor(model => ((CheckPaymentMethodInfo) model.Transaction.PaymentMethod).BankName,
                                new {htmlAttributes = new {@class = "form-control"}})
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => ((CheckPaymentMethodInfo) model.Transaction.PaymentMethod).BankName, "",
                                new {@class = "text-danger"})
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => ((CheckPaymentMethodInfo) model.Transaction.PaymentMethod).RoutingNumber,
                            new {@class = "control-label col-md-2"})
                        <div class="col-md-10">
                            @Html.EditorFor(model => ((CheckPaymentMethodInfo) model.Transaction.PaymentMethod).RoutingNumber,
                                new {htmlAttributes = new {@class = "form-control"}})
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => ((CheckPaymentMethodInfo) model.Transaction.PaymentMethod).RoutingNumber, "",
                                new {@class = "text-danger"})
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => ((CheckPaymentMethodInfo) model.Transaction.PaymentMethod).AccountNumber,
                            new {@class = "control-label col-md-2"})
                        <div class="col-md-10">
                            @Html.EditorFor(model => ((CheckPaymentMethodInfo) model.Transaction.PaymentMethod).AccountNumber,
                                new {htmlAttributes = new {@class = "form-control"}})
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => ((CheckPaymentMethodInfo) model.Transaction.PaymentMethod).AccountNumber, "",
                                new {@class = "text-danger"})
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => ((CheckPaymentMethodInfo) model.Transaction.PaymentMethod).CheckNumber,
                            new {@class = "control-label col-md-2"})
                        <div class="col-md-10">
                            @Html.EditorFor(model => ((CheckPaymentMethodInfo) model.Transaction.PaymentMethod).CheckNumber,
                                new {htmlAttributes = new {@class = "form-control"}})
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => ((CheckPaymentMethodInfo) model.Transaction.PaymentMethod).CheckNumber, "",
                                new {@class = "text-danger"})
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            }
```

When the form is rendered however the fields are named incorrectly and the submitted form contains null for the PaymentMethod.

```
            <div id="check_payment">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label col-md-2" for="BankName">BankName</label>
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        <input class="form-control text-box single-line" id="BankName" name="BankName" type="text" value="" />
                        <span class="field-validation-valid text-danger" data-valmsg-for="BankName" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label col-md-2" for="RoutingNumber">RoutingNumber</label>
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        <input class="form-control text-box single-line" id="RoutingNumber" name="RoutingNumber" type="text" value="" />
                        <span class="field-validation-valid text-danger" data-valmsg-for="RoutingNumber" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label col-md-2" for="AccountNumber">AccountNumber</label>
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        <input class="form-control text-box single-line" id="AccountNumber" name="AccountNumber" type="text" value="" />
                        <span class="field-validation-valid text-danger" data-valmsg-for="AccountNumber" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label col-md-2" for="CheckNumber">CheckNumber</label>
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        <input class="form-control text-box single-line" id="CheckNumber" name="CheckNumber" type="text" value="" />
                        <span class="field-validation-valid text-danger" data-valmsg-for="CheckNumber" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: Even if you did get your naming conventions correct, you would still have a problem getting the concrete type back after posting.

Comment: So what should I do? Not use inherited types in my models?

Comment: I ended up passing both types into the view inside the ViewModel then assign the correct one to the transaction after the form is submitted. This solved the problem, but seems hacky for some reason.

Comment: One option is to create a view model that has both type's data structures and create the correct type based on the funding method

Comment: Yep, that's what I did. Thanks.